error Assertion failed uv_thread_create when building Docker image
what I have done before
I am new on development with angular and I don't succeed to setup node on my computer. then I found node images here :
https://hub.docker.com/_/node/
I build a image based on node:22-alpine and I succeed to make lots of things with angular.
issue is coming
the next test I want to do is to build a android mobile application from an angular project. then I found this who need to install Java Development Kit :
https://docs.nativescript.org/setup/linux
first problem is that alpine don't have the command apt-get installed. then I thought it will be quick to build a new docker image based on Debian Bookworm but my problem is here.
I use a simple Dockerfile like that :
FROM node:22
RUN npm -v

then a use the command docker build -t test-22 . and I got that :
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/2 : FROM node:22
---> 16d00b0a86e6
Step 2/2 : RUN npm -v
---> Running in f7a643373e56

#  node[6]: std::unique_ptr<long unsigned int> node::WorkerThreadsTaskRunner::DelayedTaskScheduler::Start() at ../src/node_platform.cc:68
#  Assertion failed: (0) == (uv_thread_create(t.get(), start_thread, this))

----- Native stack trace -----

1: 0xf6f027 node::Assert(node::AssertionInfo const&) [node]
2: 0xff8d1e node::WorkerThreadsTaskRunner::WorkerThreadsTaskRunner(int) [node]
3: 0xff8dfc node::NodePlatform::NodePlatform(int, v8::TracingController*, v8::PageAllocator*) [node]
4: 0xf240db  [node]
5: 0xf2558c node::Start(int, char**) [node]
6: 0x7fbe0f05924a  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
7: 0x7fbe0f059305 __libc_start_main [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
8: 0xe7127e _start [node]
Aborted (core dumped)
The command '/bin/sh -c npm -v' returned a non-zero code: 134

there is no problem with node:22-alpine but I got that with node:22 and I test also node:20 which do the same error message.
has someone an idea how to solve that ? or maybe an advice on how to begin on a simple mobile application for android ?

Docker build fails and exit with error code 139 suggests a ulimit issue.  That seems slightly unlikely in Docker, but does the proposed fix help?  From what I've seen around mobile-development setups, tools like device emulators are also unlikely to work in containers, and I might focus on trying to get a host-based development environment work over trying to fix a broken isolated tool set that will be hard to use.

I add the ulimit command and the error is the same. for development environment, I only found host for api or download applications upgrade. is it possible de find development environment ready to use without need of installing everything by myself ?

@DavidMaze I read the link you propose and a few link further, I found someone who speaks about a docker not up to date. I feel that this can be my problem but I cannot change that now then I cannot confirm that this solves my issue.
